# CSS - Horizontal white space on display table and table-cell divs

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a problem with an horizontal white space that appears inside a div without any reason. I mean, I cant' figure out WHY it appears, it just doesn't make any sense.

Here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzNzx/)

The layout should be two columns: one right and one left and the latter one is larger. The problem is that on the right div I see contents shown regularly, with all alignments well shown. On the left one, its contents are lower, I mean it seems like it has a padding-top of about 5px, but there's no padding at all. The white space is INSIDE the left table-cell div, because even with plain text inside it ("Lorem ipsum"), the text is shown lower than the contents inside the right div.

HTML code is:

```
<div id="main_contents_cage">
    <div id="main_contents_left">
        <table> ... some content ... </table>
    </div>

    <div id="main_contents_right">
        ... some other content ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
#main_contents_cage { display: table; }
#main_contents_left, #main_contents_right { display: table-cell; }

#main_contents_left { width: 742px; }
#main_contents_right { width: 246px; border-left: 1px solid #C6C6C6; }
```

I searched the internet and StackOv for anyone else with the same problem without finding anyone with the same issue. Similar, but not the same at all!

I tried giving border-collapse/border-spacing to all the elements (once each, then just the "table" one, then just the "table-cell" ones, then the three of them): nothing.

I tried changing the contents of the table-cell divs, without any different result (replacing the table with other divs, or just plain text....).

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Could you put it in a jsfiddle? Makes it easier to help if we can see

Comment: Sure, question corrected! With the fiddle it appears to work but I tried on my webpage and i really can't make it work!!

Comment: Does Chrome's element inspector show any CSS being applied to the element that you're not expecting?

Comment: Nothing: I mean, in FF (firebug) and in Chrome with Developer tools on, nothing is giving any clue of the reason that white space appears.
The only way of making it work is to give the table-cell elements a vertical-align: top property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this same issue.  I too was able to "fix" the issue by assigning "vertical-align: top" to the table-cell element.  This only appears to be an issue in Chorme.  For me, it was the right column only (rather the left like in your example)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the div with the class of "main_contents_left" have table tags that contain no children row or grandchildren cells, could that have something to do with it?

Here is a link to my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcyxa/), if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out: I need to add "vertical-align: top" to the "table-cell" divs in order for the content to display with no white space on the top!

I know in the fiddles it works but I really can't make it work on my webpage, even with no CSS (just the one I need...). (FF 13, Chrome 20).

Thank you